# Github Actions equivalent of travis Tag is Present

Tags: github-actions, travis-ci

Is there an equivalent action for Travis's 'Tag is present' condition? I have a workflow that I'm migrating and this condition is used quite often.

Comment: can you post an example and/or an expected behavior, please?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with travis so I don't know the actual behavior. However this is an example if `type != pull_request AND tag IS present AND branch =~ <regex>` run a deployment script.

Comment: Please specify the expected behavior. Without knowing that, it's difficult to suggest an alternative :)

Comment: It's no longer needed. Thanks!